# Infinite while not working with os.execvp

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, shell

I am programming in python which involves me implementing a shell in Python in Linux. I am trying to run standard unix commands by using os.execvp(). I need to keep asking the user for commands so I have used an infinite while loop. However, the infinite while loop doesn't work. I have tried searching online but they're isn't much available for Python. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

This is the code I have written so far:

```
import os
import shlex

def word_list(line):
    """Break the line into shell words."""
    lexer = shlex.shlex(line, posix=True)
    lexer.whitespace_split = False
    lexer.wordchars += '#$+-,./?@^='
    args = list(lexer)
    return args



def main():
    while(True):
        line = input('psh>')
        split_line = word_list(line)

        if len(split_line) == 1:
            print(os.execvp(split_line[0],[" "]))
        else:
           print(os.execvp(split_line[0],split_line))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So when I run this and put in the input "ls" I get the output "HelloWorld.py" (which is correct) and "Process finished with exit code 0". However I don't get the output "psh>" which is waiting for the next command. No exceptions are thrown when I run this code.

Comment: "Not working" is not a problem description. Tell us specifically _how_ it is not working (exceptions? error messages? simply not doing what you want?), and give us all relevant input and output.

Comment: Did you read [the execvp documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.execvp)? Calling this function replaces the current process with the subcommand, so of course it ends the current process. Use `os.call` or better yet, the `subprocess` module.

Comment: I have read the module for this in python. I am not allowed to use os or subprocess.

Comment: That's a contradictory statement as you're already using `os`. And if you've read the documentation you should understand that it's simply impossible to do this using `os.execvp` - you want `os.call` or the similar functions that create a subprocess _without_ ending the parent process. Oh, and "I have tried searching online but they're isn't much available for Python" - that's simply wrong, all built-in python modules are extensively documented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code does not work because it uses [`os.execvp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execvp). `os.execvp` **replaces the current process image completely with the executing program**, your running process **becomes** the `ls`.

To execute a **subprocess** use the aptly named [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

---

In case of an **ill-advised** programming exercise then you need to:

```
# warning, never do this at home!
pid = os.fork()
if not pid:
    os.execvp(cmdline) # in child
else:
    os.wait(pid) # in parent
```

`os.fork` returns twice, giving the pid of child in parent process, zero in child process.

Comment: os.fork is not by any means ill advised. it is how the sub process module works underneath after all. Everyone should be able to use fork and exec to achieve their goal prior to using sub process in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to run like a shell you are looking for os.fork() . Call this before you call os.execvp() and it will create a child process. os.fork() returns the process id. If it is 0 then you are in the child process and can call os.execvp(), otherwise continue with the code. This will keep the while loop running. You can have the original process either wait for it to complete os.wait(), or continue without waiting to the start of the while loop.  The pseudo code on page 2 of this link should help https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci340s2c/assignments/A1/A1.pdf

Comment: I am in this guys class. These are the commands the lecturer told us to use for the assignment linked above.

Comment: For anyone who is not doing a school assignment **Antti's answer** will probably be better